# Unable to hide a component on vf page using JavaScript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I'm trying to hide an inputfield on visualforce page based on some condition. So, i started with below code, but unable to hide the inputfield on page load itself. 
Both the alert messages displayed before and after the js code are executing well. but, the component is not hiding from the page(able to grey it out successfully with the below code, but not hiding it).
Could not use rerender functionality, as my section contains rich text area., and rerender is not working for components containing rich text area. 
My code below:

```
    <apex:page id="pageid" standardcontroller="account">
  <apex:form id="formid">
      <apex:pageblock id="pbid">
          <apex:pageblocksection id="pbsid">
              <apex:inputfield id="phoneid" value="{!account.phone}"/>
          </apex:pageblocksection>
      </apex:pageblock>
  </apex:form>

  <script>
     alert('d2 opens now');
     try{
         document.getElementById("pageid:formid:pbid:pbsid:phoneid").visible=false;
         }catch(e){
         alert(e)
         }
         alert('d2 opens now1');
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks in advance, Friend!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("pageid:formid:pbid:pbsid:phoneid").style.display ='none';
```

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, using jQuery would be best and easiest, as you can simply do this:

```
$("[id$=phoneid]").hide();
```

This will not break if someone changes the markup of the page, since it just uses the id of the `apex:inputField`.

Comment: Be aware that this selector will hide every element in the DOM which has an ID value that ends with `phoneid`. [jQuery ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) documentation. If the `inputField` is defined within a repeating structure (repeat, table, etc.), it will hide every one of them.

Comment: Actually, it wouldn't work on a `apex:repeat`, because each row gets the id modified to be like `phoneid:0`, `phoneid:1`, etc. Using an ends-with would work only for non-repeated elements.

Comment: @sfdcfox your assertion is incorrect. In a repeated element situation, the repeater index comes prior to the tag ID value. `repeatThing:0:phoneid`, `repeatThing:1:phoneid`, `repeatThing:2:phoneid`, `repeatThing:3:phoneid`, etc. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm

Comment: You're correct. I think it used to be the other way around, though; I could have sworn that's the way it was before. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to have the `inputfield` hidden on page load, you can add the CSS class 'hidden' to the tag directly. Salesforce pages all have this class defined within their stylesheets.

```
<apex:page id="pageid" standardcontroller="account">
  <apex:form id="formid">
      <apex:pageblock id="pbid">
          <apex:pageblocksection id="pbsid">
              <apex:inputfield id="phoneid" value="{!account.phone}" styleClass="hidden" />
          </apex:pageblocksection>
      </apex:pageblock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

If you want to ensure future maintainability, you should define your own `hidden` class within your markup. This will prevent future platform stylesheet changes from changing the behavior of your solution.

```
<apex:page id="pageid" standardcontroller="account">
    <style type="text/css">
        .hidden { display: none; }
    </style>
    <apex:form id="formid">
        <apex:pageblock id="pbid">
            <apex:pageblocksection id="pbsid">
                <apex:inputfield id="phoneid" value="{!account.phone}" styleClass="hidden" />
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

If you'd like to hide it with script you can use markup like this, leveraging the `$Component` global to dynamically retrieve the ID of your `inputField` in the page hierarchy. Be aware that using this method will allow the `inputField` to be visible in the browser until the script executes and hides it.

The CSS method above will hide the field as the page is rendered, where the script method will hide it after the script runs. Allowing the user to see the field, even temporarily, isn't the optimal implementation.

```
<apex:page id="pageid" standardcontroller="account">    
    <apex:form id="formid">
        <apex:pageblock id="pbid">
            <apex:pageblocksection id="pbsid">
                <apex:inputfield id="phoneid" value="{!account.phone}" />
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('{!$Component.pageid.formid.pbid.pbsid.phoneid}').style.display = 'none';
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Documentation: [Best Practices for Accessing Component IDs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm)

When using and troubleshooting the `$Component` markup, be sure to look at the rendered source code for the page in the browser. This should simplify the steps to figure out what's not correct in the VF markup.

If the path to your component is correct, the HTML will have the hierarchical ID in the rendered source. `document.getElementById('pageid:formid:pbid:pbsid:phoneid').style.display = 'none';`

If the path to the component was not correct and it couldn't be located using what you've provided, the rendered source code will have a blank value where you would expect to see the ID. Like this: `document.getElementById('').style.display = 'none';`

Answer (score 1):

As Venkatesh said, using`.style.display ='none'` should be enough, but I see a problem that your layout marking is not flexible, because your js would be broken each time as you or somebody will make changes in layout. As you can see the id for `<apex:inputfield` component generated by adding ids of all outer component and adding new component to this hierarchy will broke your js.
You can try to use html input field instead `<apex:inputfield` where id would be the same as you wrote in the code.