# Assign rendered value using javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, rendered

Folks,

below is my code,

```
<apex:inputtext value="{Account.Name}" rendered="True"/>

<apex:commandbutton>
```

am not using controller here, so i want to change the value to rendered="False" using javascript. is it possible to change rendered="False" using javascript?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're after here? It's a bit confusing which is why the community put it on hold.

Comment: Rendering of VF pages is done server side, as a consequence all rendered attributes and expressions are processed server side - meaning you can't do what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using java script. For you solution you can follow [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14660/unable-to-hide-a-component-on-vf-page-using-javascript) post.

Comment: my scenario: Rendered = False,  i want to change False to true using JavaScript.

Comment: If you are using document.getElementById('').style.display = 'none' syntax then instead of 'none' you can use 'block'.

Comment: Pramod! i want to use Rendered Tag and need to pass True/False using JavaScript.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks @SamuelDeRycke. I got your point and keep this in mind for future.

Comment: Actually, my apologies. I only now see you linked to an in-site answer. In that case if the question is similar or in essence the same you can flag it as a duplicate.